# How to make jbutton sum up the values of my jradiobuttons

Tags: jframe, jbutton, jtextfield, jradiobutton

I'm making a project in jFrame. It has 15 jRadiobuttons. What I want is a jButton to add the selected jRadioButtons and display the sum in a jTextField. Can anyone help me? I've been doing this for 3 days and cant get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have numbers as values of the radiobuttons?
Then try it like this:
When the button is clicked, go through a foreach loop of all radiobuttons.
in the loop, check if they are selected. If they are, you add their value to the Sum.

Is that what you were asking for?

EDIT

1. You create A List containing all radiobuttons.
2. In the Listener of the Button you write:

   ```
   int sum = 0;
   //foreach loop
   for (jRadiobutton rbutton : rbuttons){
     //Check if the button is selected
     if (rbutton.isSelected){
       sum += rbutton.Value;
     }
   }
   ```

I hope this is good enough explained.
Maybe the Syntax isn't correct, i haven't used java for a while now...

Comment: Yes sir, all the radiobuttons have number values. What i want is for me to be able to pick any radiobuttons and when i click the jbutton it sums the total amount. Im having trouble w/ that one.

Comment: @ChesterVacalares Have you tried it the way I wrote in the answer?

Comment: Not really. Can you instruct me in layman terms. Im actually new w/ this.

Comment: @ChesterVacalares Answer is edited. Is it clear now and if yes, does it work?

Comment: do i have to do this in every radio button?

Comment: @ChesterVacalares You have to do this in your Button to calculate the sum. (jButton in your Question)

Comment: im getting errors in jRadioButton, rbuttons and if(rbutton.isSelected). Am i missing something?

Comment: @ChesterVacalares Like I said, the syntax may be wrong... after isSelected put () and rbuttons would be the List you have to create.

Comment: i get the JRadioButton now. Whats left is the rbuttons and value that is still error.

Comment: @ChesterVacalares maybe .Value doesn't exist. is there something like getValue() or getText()?
And for rbuttons you have to put

    List<jRadioButton> rbuttons = new ArrayList<jRadioButton>() at the beginning of your code and add the radio buttons to it

Comment: can you show me an example.? I need this for tomorrow.

Comment: @ChesterVacalares sorry i have no java environment. Can you somehow upload somewhere your Code and i can look at it?

Comment: got it... Thank you so much

Comment: is livenet russian sir? i cant really register. Do you have gmail or yahoo?

Comment: @ChesterVacalares Sent you the Code. And no, livenet is from Switzerland. And you don't have to register... But it worked so what

Comment: total += (int) button.getText(); is in error. It says "incompatible types: String can not be converted to int."

Comment: @ChesterVacalares I sent you a solution for that in a Mail. Is it still showing the error?

Comment: I've sent you an email. Just a heads up incase you missed it